# How can I transfer the user to another server without changing the url

Tags: asp.net, iis, redirect

In my asp.net website, I am working with three servers with three different providers. the DNS points to one. When users login, I want to use a lookup table to find the proper server where the user info resides and transfer the users there. The main restrictions is:
I cannot use a different sub domain or url for each server. (the user would see a www.example.com/userData in all cases)

I understand that I cannot use server.transfer because they have different httpcontext. Also this is not a load balancing issue even though each server has its own IIS and SQL server. The location of each user is determined beforehand. 
What are my options to do so?

Comment: by the time you find a proper server using your look-up table, is there any particular reason that you don't get the required info from the destination server using its database connection rather than transfer the user to another server ?

Comment: Why do you need to redirect in order to look up user info ? Aren't you storing it in a database ? If so, why the need for this ? Seems like a strange architecture to me, can you explain it more ?

Comment: Sure, sorry if the info was not sufficient. We have the dns server pointing to www.example.com (server A). Now, we have a new server in another country with a different provider (server B). When the user logs in server A, we would like to locate it and transfer it to the Server B if needed (both iis and database are located in the new server too). I have considered using a subdomain and point it to server B, but that's not what my manager wants. What would be your suggestion for this weird architecture?